# What if my database has no primary key how do i map it to my jpa entity?

Tags: java, jpa

I randomly put any Column as an id but some records of a particular column had duplicate data even though the the data in db was different, how do I solve this issue with out adding a primary key to the database.

Comment: JPA doesn't need primary key. But it needs a column (or a set of columns) that 1. uniquely identifies the row, 2. is immutable. If you have such a column (or set of columns), you'd better make it the primary key anyway. If you don't, then you can't use JPA. Not having a PK is a big, big, mistake (whether you use JPA or not).

Comment: If i donot have a unique set of columns should i use the id annotations on all the entity class variables as i have seen if i place on a single variable of entity there us some musmatch of records fetched by entity

Comment: If the full set of columns make it unique, then you can do that, yes. But your entity will be effectively immutable. Why don't you fix the database and add a unique column?

Comment: I cannot change it as it is a business requirement ,i donot want to persist data using jpa i only want to read it so making all columns id in entity class wont cause problem right? A background procedure will update data for me

Comment: It will cause a problem if at least two rows contain the same values and you try loading these two rows in the same session.

Comment: Two rows can have same value but in rare scenario, can we use order by rownum ,will that help.is there any way i can still use jpa,how can we make it work

Comment: JPA needs an **identity** for every entity instance. Ordering rows won't help.

Comment: so any way to get it to work without adding any extra column in the database.

Comment: is this a downfall of jpa or all the orm based on the same principle .

Comment: and rownum is a unique identifier for each row right so it will act as an id i suppose ?

Comment: All the ORMs are based on the same principle. You should not have a table without PK. That's one of the essential rules of database design. Otherwise, there is no way to refer to a given row.

Comment: So you mean to say there is no way out apart from i using the id on all the columns and hope there is no duplicate values

Comment: That's what I'm saying from the start: it needs a column (or a set of columns) that 1. uniquely identifies the row, 2. is immutable.

Comment: it will make it immutable but still i can fetch values right as i am not persiting , some i am asking so many question this ia new scenario for me

Comment: @Rahul Singh, it's not clear to me how would you use such an entity? Do you need it only to convert SQL result into a Java object? Or do you connect the entity to other entities? What comes to my mind is to call native SQL query and convert the results to a Java object, or to add a view to your DB which contains the same data and generated column with unique values. Or, if your table has a foreign key to another table, you may map it as an embeddable collection, which does not require primary key.

Comment: I just need to convert sql object to java object but i donot want to write native query as there are charts that i have to display and string will create problem,i want to use jpa class queries